# Unable to login with the Facebook using Facebook SDK in android if I have the Facebook app

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-login

Unable to login with the Facebook using Facebook SDK in android if I have the Facebook app.

Here If I uninstall the Facebook app and then try to login with the facebook, it works fine by navigating to the browser. But it fails to login if the device has the Facebook app.

com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:12.3.0

[image]

Comment: Make sure you have added hash in facebook developer console.

Comment: @VishalThakkar I have added the hash already in my developer console